# Can't create database model for Oracle using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

We have an existing .NET application that connects to an Oracle database using a 3rd party ORM (Telerik); we will be migrating to Entity Framework.

#### Preliminary setup:

Create a new project in the solution. Install nuget packages:

- EntityFramework 6.1.3
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.2.1100
- Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework 12.2.1100

#### Steps:

- right click project -> add -> new item
- data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model (enter name) -> Add (next page)
- EF Designer from database (next page)
- Click "new connection" button -> (new dialog)
- Enter username and password, TNS connection like so:
- [image: connection_info]
- test connection (test connection succeeded) hit ok to go back to "choose your data connection" dialog
- "yes include sensitive data" and save connection string in app.config like so:
- [image]
- click next

#### The problem:

The dialog closes. There's no error message. There's no option to select tables. Nothing happens. No connection string in `app.config` is updated. There is no `.edmx` in the project. It just silently fails.

I've tried minor deviations to the above (different login credentials, don't save in app.config, don't include sensitive info, connection info instead of TNS, create a blank `.edmx` and later update it) but I can't get any tables automatically generated.

Any ideas?

Perhaps there is some way to enable verbose logging to a file somehow?

#### Additional info:

- Windows 7 Enterprise sp1 x64
- Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following are required to use Entity Framework to generate a model from a database without silently crashing:

- 32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio
- Alternatively referred to as "ODTwithODAC121012" or "ODTwithODAC122010" etc depending on version

Available at http://www.oracle.com/partners/campaign/utilsoft-086879.html

Newer versions (including 64bit versions) can be found [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/net-downloads.html).