# Entity Framework 6 not displaying database tables after display successful popup

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, odp.net, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have installed all required tools and nuget packages in project, as below.

**Oracle version: Our DB Version is Oracle 11g Release 2**

1. Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2022 (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OracleCorporation.OracleDeveloperToolsForVisualStudio2022)
2. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
3. Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework

[image]

I am trying to connect **ORACLE** database into my **.net 4.5 framework** project by using entity framework 6.x.x. I want to generate an edmx file, and for this I am performing below steps.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now here, I am expecting the list of tables from DB, but it navigate to STEP-1.

[image]

Let me know if I need to perform other steps.

Comment: the way it silently return to the first step sounds like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48831078). but its weird that it fails despite having the two required packages.

Comment: Yes, I believe I have installed all required tools/ nugets. I have attached 2 new images of installed packages.